# Regex non-capturing group is capturing

Tags: html, regex, anchor

I have this regex

```
(?:\<a[^*]href="(http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf)"+?[^>]*?)>
```

The point of this regex is to capture every closing tag ('>') of an anchor that has an href that starts with "http://" or ends with ".pdf".

The regex works, however it is capturing the first part of the anchor, which I absolutely need to NOT capture.

In the following samples all are matching except second (which is fine) but only the last bracket should be captured and it is not the case.

```
<a href="http://blabla">omg</a>
<a href="blabla">omg</a>
<a href="http://blabla.pdf">omg</a>
<a href="/blabla.pdf">omg</a>
```

For example: If we take the first match which is :

```
<a href="http://blabla">
```

I only want to capture the last bracket (the one I surounded with parenthesis) :

```
<a href="http://blabla"(>)
```

So why the non-capturing group is capturing? And how can I only grab the last bracket of the anchor

Even if I streamline my regex to the following, it still doesnt work

```
(?:\<a[^*]href="http://[^"]+"+[^>]*)(>)
```

Thank you,

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to capture within a string?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to use a HTML parser and apply a regexp to each href attribute.

Comment: @mikerobi that could be good to, the thing is that the only tool I have is a plain find and replace I cannot isolate any captured group, the match need to be the string I want to replace

Comment: What language are you using? PHP?

Comment: Also, why do you have question marks (`?`) following the pluses (`+`) and asterisks (`*`)?

Comment: using a find a replace tool in a cms. But I have the feeling that the tool is using javascript's regex lib

Comment: @compeek that's the greedy operator. It is absolutely not needed here, just a safety. Sometimes I forget it and Im like wth is going on. I just always put the greedy when i dont need extensive capture

Comment: Ahh, okay. I guess that's new to me since I've never needed it. :)

Comment: What’s `[^*]` for? ALSO you’re missing some stuff because you shouldn’t assume that the `href` field for the anchor falls exactly after the `a` or that there is one single space, nor should you assume double instead of single quotes, nor should you forget about script and comment issues, nor you should forget that sometimes `>` are perfectly fine like in quoted field values, nor should you match case sensitively under HTML which isn’t, nor should you be escaping the angle bracket like `\<`, &c&c&c. Although I do know an easy regex for doing all this quite handily, this margin is too narrow. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're conflating two distinct concepts: *capturing* and *consuming*.  Regexes normally consume whatever they match; that's just how they work.  Additionally, most regex flavors let you use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to pluck out specific parts of the overall match.  (The overall match is often referred to as the zero'th capturing group, but that's just a figure of speech.)

It sounds like you're trying to match a whole `<A>` tag, but only consume the final `>`.  That's not possible in most regex flavors, JavaScript included.  But if you're using Perl or PHP, you could use `\K` to spoof the match start position:

```
(?i)<a\s+[^>]+?href="http://[^"]+"[^>]*\K>
```

And in .NET you could use a lookbehind (which, like a lookahead, matches without consuming):

```
(?i)"(?<=<a\s+[^>]+?href="http://[^"]+"[^>]*)>
```

Of the other flavors that support lookbehinds, most place restrictions on them that render them unusable for this task.

Comment: looking back at this response, a year later with more experience in the subject. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite your regex  as :

```
(?:\<a[^*]href="(?:http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf)"+?[^>]*?)(>)
   non capture __^^                                    ^ ^
                                             capture __|_|
```

As Tony Lukasavage said, there is an unnecessary non-capture group, and, moreover, there is no need to escape `<`, so it becomes:

```
  <a[^*]href="(?:http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf)"+?[^>]*?(>)
non capture __^^                                    ^ ^
                                          capture __|_|
```

Comment: you have an unnecessary non-capture group around everything before the final bracket he actually wants to capture.

Comment: @Tony Lukasavage: you're right, but it works, i've just taken the OP's regex as it was. It doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly that you want to match just the greater-than sign (`>`) that's part of the closing anchor tag, this should do it:

```
\<a[^*]href="(http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf)"+?[^>]*?(>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your request correctly...

```
\<a[^*]href="(?:http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf)"+?[^>]*?(>)
```

Comment: both mine and compeek's regex will perform the pattern match you are looking for, as we understand it.  What exactly is not working with it?

Comment: well unless the regex tester im using is wrong. I'm using this http://regexpal.com/

Comment: I'm using the exact same tester, and it working just fine for me. :\

Comment: It is just highlighting the closing bracket?

Comment: Oh, okay. I see why you think it's not working. No, it's highlighting the whole tag. But we're all thinking you're using a backreference, and backreference 1 would correctly match just the `>`. Give me a minute to try something else.

Comment: Alright, I cannot anyhow use any kind of backreference or refer to a matched group, only the bracket need to be highlighted

Comment: Using a lookbehind would do it, I think, but JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds. Since you're using the find and replace tool and can't even write any code to work around it, I'm not sure it's possible to do what you need.

Comment: @Compeek yeah thats what I thought to XD... :(

Comment: Couldn't you just copy and paste the text from the CMS into Notepad++ or something? Notepad++ does search and replace with RegEx, including backreferences. Then just copy the modified text back to the CMS.

Comment: no it's affecting way to many pages at once. It for a full project.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are around the tag itself and the href's contents, so that's what will be captured. If you need to capture the closing > then put the parenthesis around it.

Comment: Could you explain further. Because if you mean \<a[^*]href="http://[^"]+?|[^"]+?\.pdf"+?[^>]*?(>), that wont work.