# ANT Script - replaceregexp with non-matching groups

Tags: regex, replace, ant

I was trying to use `replaceregexp` to search and replace a copyright symbol and garbage characters on multiple files but specifically from the ones who have a date in the 2000 range, so I decided to use a non-capturing group to match the number after the copyright symbol and replace ONLY the copyright symbol. 
But for some reason it still replaces the symbol and the number.

For example, I would match:

```
© 2007 Mail Services Bla Bla Bla
```

And the expected result would be:

```
C 2007 Mail Services Bla Bla Bla
```

But I get:

```
C Bla Bla Bla
```

Here is my code:

```
<replaceregexp match="${match.exp}" replace="${replace.str}" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${parent.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.js"/>
        <include name="**/*.jsp"/>
        <include name="**/*.xml"/>
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
        <include name="**/*.css"/>
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
        <!-- Excluding some files -->
        <exclude name="**/yu.js"/>
        <exclude name="**/JSMenu.js"/>
        <exclude name="**/jqueryTimerPack.js."/>
        <exclude name="**/jqu.js"/>
        <exclude name="**/jqui.js"/>
        <exclude name="**/AM.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
(?:\s*)(©|ï¿½|Â©)(?:\s*20\d\d,\sMail Services)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-capturing group is still consumed and replaced, it just isn't "captured" in the sense that the characters matched by the pattern in that group aren't stored for you. (see this answer: [Regex non-capturing group is capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900289/regex-non-capturing-group-is-capturing))

Instead you should capture the groups and use them to rebuild the desired string.

For example, if you're regex is `(?:\s*)(©|ï¿½|Â©)(?:\s*20\d\d,\sMail Services)`, try instead using `(\s*)(©|ï¿½|Â©)(\s*20\d\d,\sMail Services)` and a replace string of something like `\1C\2`. I'm not sure if the comma in the last group was intended, since it wouldn't match the examples you provided.

Comment: That works perfectly!, the comma wasn't needed but the replace string would be \1c\3 I believe.